# F# CSVProvider only reports first column data

Tags: csv, f#

[image: firstRow is of type string]

While using CSVprovider on any csv file, I used the below:

http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip

```
    type statsProvider = CsvProvider<"../../FL_insurance_sample.csv",",">

    let stats = statsProvider.Load("../../FL_insurance_sample.csv")

    let firstRow = stats.Rows |> Seq.head
```

The CSVProvider only returns the data from the first column.   It does identify the columns (18) correctly and the name of the columns correctly, yet when you look at the type of rows, they're only type string, not a tuple or a structure...

see in the screenshot the type of firstRow should be a specific type e.g. tuple or structure not a string.

What am I doing wrong?  Using Visual studio 2017, FSharp 4.1, .net 4.5.2 and FSharp.Data 2.3.3

Note: this happens with several at least 3 more csv files. I picked this particular csv for demonstration only.

Comment: When I open that file in vim it all appears on one line. It turns out the file has mac line breaks (`\r`). Try switching to unix line breaks instead (`\n`)?

Comment: While the screenshot you included is useful for showing the values you're seeing in the debugger, it's usually best to include your code as *text* rather than as a screenshots, since code in screenshots can't be searched for. Could you please edit your question to include your code as text, in addition to your screenshot?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I changed the text to Windows CRLF but the effect was the same

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem: the sample CSV file you provided worked just fine for me. But then, I'm using VS Code, not Visual Studio; it's possible that the source of the problem is somewhere in Visual Studio 2017 rather than in FSharp.Data. Here's what I did:

1. Create a new, empty project folder.
2. Copy the Paket bootstrapper into it, in `.paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe`.
3. Run `paket init`.
4. Edit the `paket.dependencies` file to add `FSharp.Data`.
5. Run `paket install`.
6. Run `paket generate-load-scripts`, which created a bunch of scripts in the `.paket/load` folder to load all the dependencies at once. (I *love* this feature for scripting!)
7. Created `script.fsx` with the following content:

   ```
   #load ".paket/load/net452/FSharp.Data.fsx"
   open FSharp.Data

   type Csv = CsvProvider<"/home/rmunn/Downloads/tmp/csv/FL_insurance_sample.csv">
   let data = Csv.GetSample()

   printfn "%A" data.Headers

   let firstRow = data.Rows |> Seq.head
   printfn "%A" firstRow
   ```
8. In VS Code, selected the entire script file and pressed Alt+Enter to send it to the F# Interactive window.

Here's the output I got:

```
F# Interactive for F# 4.1
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;
> # silentCd @"/home/rmunn/code/fsharp/tmp/foo";;
- # 1 @"/home/rmunn/code/fsharp/tmp/foo/script.fsx"
- ;;

(snip the copy of my script that F# Interactive echoed)

[Loading /home/rmunn/code/fsharp/tmp/foo/.paket/load/net452/Zlib.Portable.fsx
 Loading /home/rmunn/code/fsharp/tmp/foo/.paket/load/net452/FSharp.Data.fsx]
namespace FSI_0002.Zlib

namespace FSI_0002.FSharp

Some
  [|"policyID"; "statecode"; "county"; "eq_site_limit"; "hu_site_limit";
    "fl_site_limit"; "fr_site_limit"; "tiv_2011"; "tiv_2012";
    "eq_site_deductible"; "hu_site_deductible"; "fl_site_deductible";
    "fr_site_deductible"; "point_latitude"; "point_longitude"; "line";
    "construction"; "point_granularity"|]
(119736, "FL", "CLAY COUNTY", 498960M, 498960M, 498960M, 498960M, 498960M,
 792148.9M, 0M, 9979.2M, 0, 0, 30.102261M, -81.711777M, "Residential", "Masonry",
 1)
type Csv = FSharp.Data.CsvProvider<...>
val data : FSharp.Data.CsvProvider<...>
val firstRow : FSharp.Data.CsvProvider<...>.Row =
  (119736, "FL", "CLAY COUNTY", 498960M, 498960M, 498960M, 498960M, 498960M,
   792148.9M, 0M, 9979.2M, 0, 0, 30.102261M, -81.711777M, "Residential",
   "Masonry", 1)
val it : unit = ()
```

However, all did not go *entirely* smoothly. When I then tried to process every row, I got the following exception:

> System.Exception: Couldn't parse row 2439 according to schema: Expecting Int32 in fl_site_deductible, got 68817.6

(I've omitted the traceback because it won't be particularly helpful to you to know which line number in FSharp.Data threw that exception).

The cause of this problem can be seen in the [CsvProvider documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html), in the "Controlling the column types" section, which reads:

> By default, the CSV type provider checks the first 1000 rows to infer the types, but you can customize it by specifying the InferRows static parameter of CsvProvider. If you specify 0 the entire file will be used.

There are two ways you can solve the "Inferred int but should have been decimal" problem. One would be to add `InferRows=0` to your `CsvProvider` type definition. The other way would be to specify an explicit schema to tell the CsvProvider which rows it's going to get wrong by looking only at the first 1,000. (If your data set is huge, this is far preferable since looking through all the rows to infer data types would take far too long). See the documentation for examples, but you'd do something like `Schema="fl_site_deductible=decimal"`.

So if you can't get your code to work in Visual Studio, see if VS Code (with the Ionide-Paket, Ionide-FSharp, and Ionide-FAKE extensions) works for you instead.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I need to integrate this with a larger base of code.   Moving to VSCode would make this impractical (I have tried VS2015 from scratch though and the same issue)   The issue happens with several (probably all) csv files.   You seem to be running a mac or some sort of linux so that might make a difference.  I'm on Windows.